# @user.profile_create(user_profile) is not persisted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, task

With rails 6.0.2.1 and ruby 2.6.5

I have a task to create users and their profiles

```
@data_sleeps.each do |data_sleep|

    password = UserService.password(10)
    user_data = data_sleep.attributes.slice(*User.attribute_names)
    .symbolize_keys.except(:id)
    .merge(password: password)

    @user = User.create_with(user_data).find_or_create_by(email: user_data[:email])
    user_profil = data_sleep.attributes.slice(*Profile.attribute_names)
    .symbolize_keys.except(:id, :avatar)
    .merge(user_id: @user.id)

    @user.create_profile(user_profil)

    puts "Create User #{@user.id} - #{@user.email}"
    puts "Profile data #{user_profil}"
    puts "User profile #{@user.profile}"

end
```

The puts return :

Create User 101 - xxxx@gmail.com
User profile {:last_name=>"", :first_name=>"", :website=>"", :professional=>true, :user_id=>101}
User profile2 `#<Profile:0x00007fddaa829760>`

But @user.profile is not updated !
In rails console @user.profile return nil

If I replace @user.create_profile by :

```
@profile = @user.build_profile(user_profil)
@profile.save
```

All works fine, what is wrong ?

Comment: Use `build_profile!` which will raise an exception if the input is invalid. You're just assuming that it will succeed.

Comment: After you do `@profile = @user.build_profile(user_profil)` do `@profile.errors` and look at the `details` attr. It's possible one of your validations is preventing the profile from being created, and looking at `@profile.errors` will shed some light on that.

Comment: Tnaks, but I would like to understand why @user.create_profile(user_profil) don't work

Comment: add a byebug statement after create_profile, and check for validation errors so  you can see why it is failing to create the profile.

Comment: Do you use any callback in your model ?